# multiple api clients with axios and react native

Tags: api, react-native, redux, react-redux, axios

I am trying to develop an app with RN using redux with 2 APIs. I do not know how to use "multiClientMiddleware" correctly, although i have read https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware. 
So far, my code works with one of the APIs:

```
const StockClient = axios.create({
baseURL: 'https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable',
responseType: 'json',
params: {
    token: STOCK_API
  },
})
const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(axiosMiddleware(StockClient))
```

I would like to add NewsAPI client in my store

```
const NewsClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://newsapi.org/v2',
  responseType: 'json',
  params: {
    apiKey: NEWS_API
  }
})
```

How can i also construct my Actions creators, so some of them should use either API1 or API2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[redux-axios-middleware is providing support for multiple clients please refer to the docs](https://github.com/svrcekmichal/redux-axios-middleware#multiple-clients)

```
import { multiClientMiddleware } from 'redux-axios-middleware';
createStore(
 ...
 multiClientMiddleware(
   clients, // described below
   options // optional, this will be used for all middleware if not overriden by upper options layer
 )
)
```

```
//where clients 
{
  default: {
    client: axios.create({
       baseURL:'http://localhost:8080/api',
       responseType: 'json'
    })
  },
  googleMaps: {
    client: axios.create({
        baseURL:'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api',
        responseType: 'json'
    })
  }
}
```

```
export function loadCategories() {
  return {
    type: 'LOAD',
    payload: {
      client: 'default', //here you can define client used
      request:{
        url:'/categories'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

more out of the box workaround

You can use axios client with base url for your first api.
and for api2 you can declare the routes as

```
let route1 = apiroute;
let route2 = API2_BASE_URL+ apiroute2;
let route3 = API2_BASE_URL+apiroute3;
```

the base url for the 2nd api will be called automatically

Comment: sorry, i could not get what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I need a way to combine both Clients in config file, since i can only use single Store in redux

Comment: i  hava updated the answer. plz check @RasulRukhillaev

Comment: i have read the docs of redux axios middleware. But im not sure how my Actions creators(which has URL) can select the correct baseURL out of 2
 `export const getNews = () => {
 ` return {
 `type: Actions.HEADLINES_AVAILABLE,
  payload: {
  request: 
  url: '/top-headlines?country=us'
 }}}}`

Comment: Plz check the load categories function added to the answer. You need to pass the client

Comment: yeah it worked, thanks. 
Need to put createStore(persistor, **applyMiddleware**(multiClientMiddleware))